# Get swagger data type from the corresponding Java Type

Tags: java, reflection, swagger, type-conversion

I'm using [Java Reflection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) API to get field names and their respective field types from Class objects.

Now I want to map those field types to their corresponding [swagger data type](http://swagger.io/specification/#data-types-12).

ie.:

```
String getSwaggerTypeFromJavaType(..) {
   // return swagger type as string
}
```

---

*I'm working on a project on which Swagger Spec is created manually as a json String by iterating through all the resource classes. Annotating every resource is not an option either. It would be useful if there's an existing library that I could use to do the type conversion.*